# Writing maps in code vs. in an XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, performance, xna-4.0, monogame

I am making a game in C# and XNA and will be porting it using MonoGame. I would like to know which is a better option for performance.

Should I write and type out my maps in the code of the game itself, or should I create an XML file and store it in their?

By map I mean the layout of the tile-map. It looks like this if I type it in the code:

```
map.Generate(new int[,]{
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
}, 64);
```

I am new as a programmer and any advice should help?

Thanks, BlazeCrate

Comment: It depends on how big your data is - how many lines are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be neglagable performance difference between the two as no matter which you use they both will end up being stored as some kind of in memory object. The only potential difference in "performance" is how long it will take to make that in memory object once at the start of the level loading (for something that simple it would only take a few ms extra to load, likely unnoticeable)

Do whatever is easier for you to implement and develop for.

Comment: Thanks I will use the one that I feel the most comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

Doing it in XML would allow you to design an editor, so that you can use your own GUI to design your content, allowing you to more easily generate much more complex content. It also allows you to modify your content without recompiling your game.

That said, it depends on the scale of your project, and your goals. You should choose the simpler approach if possible, if you want to eventually release it. If you choose the more complex yet more scalable approach, you run the risk of making the project too complex to finish. If your goal is to eventually release, then stay as simple as possible, but if your goal is more along the lines of learning to be a good software engineer, then choosing the more complex approach could be the way to go.

Comment: Well I am planning to release it but I am willing to do anything. I am just learning and I am only 15 so I have time to try other things. I think that I will  experiment with both and see which is easier and I like more. Heck maybe I will like XML more.